# Using type stubs for Python stdlib with mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following MWE:

```py
import hashlib


def tstfun(h: hashlib._hashlib.HASH):
    print(h)


h = hashlib.md5()
tstfun(h)
# reveal_type(h)
```

Running this as-is yields - no surprise:

```
$ python mypytest.py
<md5 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7fa645dedd90>
```

But checking this with mypy fails with:

```
$ mypy mypytest.py 
mypytest.py:4: error: Name 'hashlib._hashlib.HASH' is not defined
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Now, revealing the type on `h` (commenting in that `reveal_type` line):

```
$ mypy mypytest.py 
mypytest.py:4: error: Name 'hashlib._hashlib.HASH' is not defined
mypytest.py:10: note: Revealed type is 'hashlib._Hash'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Well, ok, then changing the type hint from `hashlib._hashlib.HASH` to `hashlib._Hash`:

```
$ python mypytest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/radarugs/hintze/s4-cnc-tools/mypytest.py", line 4, in <module>
    def tstfun(h: hashlib._HASH):
AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute '_HASH'
$ mypy mypytest.py 
mypytest.py:4: error: Name 'hashlib._HASH' is not defined
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

...which is the worst outcome.

How to check if the type stubs for the `hashlib` are correctly found and used by `mypy`? What else to check? What do I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the traceback, you used `hashlib._HASH`.

With this code:

```py
import hashlib

def tstfun(h: hashlib._Hash):
    print(h)

h = hashlib.md5()
tstfun(h)
```

Mypy reports: `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

Comment: If this can be of any help, I'm using Python 3.9.0 and Mypy 0.812.

Comment: this is soooo much a facepalm situation for me right now. thank you!!! I wrote it all-caps, and I look at this code for literally days now. omg. you saved my sanity.

Comment: does this run for you? I get a traceback: `AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute '_Hash'`, and thus have to quote this type hint

Comment: Yes, I run without error the code posted in my answer (no quotation marks needed).

Answer (score 2):

Using `hashlib._Hash` is correct, but you also need to `from __future__ import annotations` if you don't want to use quotes. See https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/2928

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import hashlib

def tstfun(h: hashlib._Hash):
    print(h)

h = hashlib.md5()
tstfun(h)
```

N.B.: `__future__.annotations` is available starting in python 3.7.0b1. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html